# situations where clean install is a must not just install?

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a question which is pretty straight forward, but hard to find an ***exact*** answer.

When we are using mvn build, what are the exact situation where we must go for clean install in order to see latest code changes in our built artifact. i.e. just install would not do that for us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Incremental+Builds

Answer (score 1):

Basically

```
mvn clean install
```

is same as

```
mvn clean && mvn install
```

so as to answer your question, its required when cleaning the files and directories generated by Maven is the primary requirement prior to doing another `install`.

---

Related to the changes in code, I would assume this is more of cleaning the *target* folder generated by Maven, hence mostly the files compiled would be overwritten when there is not much of a change.

In cases where one has removed/refactored a class from the previous build. There might be references still left if you don't clean and that would get packaged into the `jar` created thereafter.

From the [official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Incremental+Builds)(formatting mine) shared by ernest,

> But if we try to build the project with `mvn install` without any `clean` lifecycle, then we see 2 bugs
>
> - the maven build still succeeds to compile the project maven even
> - generates a jar which contains broken classes
> - moduleB does not get recompiled and is thus broken as well.

Also, a preferably suggested way is to instead use

```
mvn verify
```

Comment: How verify would help?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne `mvn verify` in general helps in cutting an unwanted phase of `install`ing your package into the local repository

Comment: `mvn verify` is to run e.g. integration tests and coverage, and also the enforcer-plugin goals. I don't understand how it affects running `mvn clean` or not. If I understand correctly (from the link shared by @ernest_k), it would not be necessary to run 'clean' if all plugins were correctly able to detect changes. However, they are not.

Comment: @gjoranv If you look at the maven phases even `mvn install` would run integration tests, just that verify is a step less... and yes, the changes to be detected is something that maven would be working on.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I didn't mention any *git repo* in my references. Are you mixing it up with something else? The only link shared by me is the same link shared by ernest in comments as well.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne If you're talking about https://github.com/struberg/maventest, its there.

Comment: Yes. Now its there. when I checked yesterday 404. Thanks. I'll go through and update.